# Can sendmmsg be used on a TCP socket?

Tags: c++, sockets, ethernet, raw-ethernet

I'm used to using send to pass a buffer of data over a TCP socket:

```
int bytes_sent = send(sockfd, buf, bytes, flags);
```

I've also used sendmmsg to send several raw ethernet frames from a single system call:

```
int frames_sent = sendmmsg(sockfd, msgvec, vlen, flags);
```

Is it possible to sendmmsg on a TCP socket? If so, are the elements of the scatter/gather array sent in sequence?

Comment: Yes. The messages are always sent in sequence, regardless of the protocol.